# JMETER - capture text from class name tags after?

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract the value - logged_user=vnahjefguzGCVke8MSyLqg%3D%3D

from the html result. refer the image[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGzOO.png)

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first suggestion is [don't post code as the image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

When it comes to extracting the logged user from the response you have 2 options:

1. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

   [image]

   textual representation of the regular expression just in case:

   ```
   logged_user=(.+?)&
   ```
2. Or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) configured like:

   [image]

In both cases you will be able to access the extracted value as `${logged_user}` where required

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri T its working fine. Sure i will avoid posting codes on images